# Laravel - Is there any auth package without using database?

Tags: authentication, laravel

What you recommend for Laravel authentication user based on JSON request and response? It should be without using database and token use for example:

I send request using JSON with username, password request and server responds as json using Auth class mechanism.

Is there any recommendations packages as json authentication usage?

I've tried Sentry but it uses MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You will have to store your user information somewhere, how else is anyone going to log in? You will need some sort of database to keep that data.

Comment: I can't use database because on remote host can be changed automatically based on another application. I think this can be useful: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust . No, it's used a DB :(

Comment: They all use a DB, there is no way around a DB. You need to store credentials somewhere.